# How do I drag and drop between two datagrids in wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop, wpftoolkit

For example, dragging a row from a datagrid table to another datagrid table?
However the other datagrid table just present the row, it manipulates the data gathered and present it in its own way.

I am using wpf toolkit. Can show me a sample example on this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/gong-wpf-dragdrop.aspx) is a good place to start. Although the tutorial is shown for ListBox, it can also be adapted for DataGrid (although I have not tried it for myself).